# Which way does spring washer go on the Ryobi circular saw

Tags: circular-saw

I just purchased a Ryobi 7 1/4 circular saw. Model CSB125. I am attaching the saw blade and I can’t remember which way to put the spring washer back on. It is beveled, shaped like an umbrella. The washer is part #49 in this diagram. Thanks

https://www.ereplacementparts.com/ryobi-csb125-csb125-714in-circular-saw-parts-c-7931_7969_507775.html

Comment: Is not https://www.ryobitools.com/support/manuals/details/CSB125 satisfactory? There are figures and instructions there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was easily answered by reading the manual

Comment: I checked the manual and didn’t see this listed anywhere.

Comment: Page 7, figures 1-3 on pages 16-17 in the linked PDF from the Ryobi website. Search for "washer".

Comment: It's also right at the top of page 8 under "Assembly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom/wide part of the spring washer #49 would go against the outer washer #27.  The blade screw #28 presses against the crown of #49 creating a locking pressure.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense

Comment: Well, at least accept the answer as correct.....

Comment: @Smokey123 If you'll take a moment to take the [tour] and to browse the [help], you'll see that the expected way of saying "thanks" around here is to click the up arrow next to the answer. Also, you should click the check mark next to the answer (that helped you the most, if there is more than 1).